Getting error on Generating Authozation key using GoogleCredentials.fromStream in Release Build
I am using new FCM HTTPS v1. While creating a release APK, I get an error. The error occurs in the GenerateAccessToken class when trying to generate a token for Firebase Cloud Messaging. Specifically, it throws an IllegalArgumentException, but I don't have the full error message.
The issue seems to be related to parsing the service account JSON or creating the GoogleCredentials object. Here are some additional steps and considerations to troubleshoot this:

Verify JSON integrity:
Ensure your service account JSON is complete and correctly formatted. The snippet you provided is truncated, which could be part of the issue.
R8/ProGuard configuration:
When creating a release APK, R8 (Android's default optimizer) or ProGuard might be stripping necessary classes. You've provided some ProGuard rules, but we might need to add more.

class GenerateAccessToken @Inject constructor(
    @ApplicationContext private val context: Context
) {
    private val url = "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/firebase.messaging"
    fun generateToken(): String = try {
        val key = "{\n" +
                "  \"type\": \"service_account\",\n" +
                "  \"project_id\": \"resea\",\n" +
                "  \"private_key_id\": \"6b78ce638b9decfd3db74e33c5632b87aaf7b0d5\",\n" +
                "  \"private_key\": \"-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----\\nM\\n-----END PRIVATE KEY-----\\n\",\n" +
                "  \"client_email\": \"firebase-adminsdk-ph923@researchhub-21392.iam.gserviceaccount.com\",\n" +
                "  \"client_id\": \"\",\n" +
                "  \"auth_uri\": \"https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth\",\n" +
                "  \"token_uri\": \"https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token\",\n" +
                "  \"auth_provider_x509_cert_url\": \"https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/certs\",\n" +
                "  \"client_x509_cert_url\": \"https://www.googleapis.com/robot/v1/metadata/x509/firebase-adminsdk-ph923%40researchhub-21392.iam.gserviceaccount.com\",\n" +
                "  \"universe_domain\": \"googleapis.com\"\n" +
                "}"
        Log.d("AAA", key)
        val credential = GoogleCredentials.fromStream(key.byteInputStream()).createScoped(url)
        credential.refreshIfExpired()
        Log.d("AAA", credential.accessToken.tokenValue)
        credential.accessToken.tokenValue
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        Log.e(TAGS.ERROR.name, "generateToken: $e")
        ""
    }
}

Error
 generateToken: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:

I tried every think but can't able to solve
Here is my progaurd
-keep class com.google.gson.reflect.TypeToken { *; }
-keep class * extends com.google.gson.reflect.TypeToken

-keepattributes AnnotationDefault,RuntimeVisibleAnnotations

-keepattributes Signature
-keepclassmembers class * {
  @com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName <fields>;
}
-keep class com.atech.core.model.** { *; }
-keep class com.atech.core.utils.JsonKt { *; }
-keep class com.google.auth.oauth2.** { *; }


-keep class org.apache.http.** { *; }
-dontwarn org.apache.http.**
  ##---------------Begin: proguard configuration for Gson  ----------
# Gson uses generic type information stored in a class file when working with fields. Proguard
# removes such information by default, so configure it to keep all of it.
-keepattributes Signature
 # For using GSON @Expose annotation
-keepattributes *Annotation*
 # Gson specific classes

 -keep class com.google.gson.stream.** { *; }
 # Application classes that will be serialized/deserialized over Gson
 -keep class com.google.gson.examples.android.model.** { *; }

Can anyone please solve this issue ?

Please abort this approach! By including the credentials you have in your question in your Android app, a malicious user can extract them from there and use them to gain administrative access to your project. --- Sending messages to a device through FCM can only be securely done from a trusted environment, such as your development machine, a server that you control, or something like Cloud Functions. By trying to do this from within the app itself, you're putting your users and yourself at risk.

But What if I just JSON file instead of this I just want to know the solution for this .
